How to get to the DBO account in Azure SQL Server
Problem:
The real problem I am solving is adding a permission to an account. Namely the SHOWPLAN. The account that I usually use to make changes to the database schema apparently does not have the ability to GRANT. The DBO account has the permissions to do a grant (I assume it does) but I do not seem to have the login for that in any of my notes.  I figure there has to be a way from the Azure Portal to get to the login or a login of similar status.
The information related to azure especially things like permissions seems to be out of date to what is on the interface.
I tried using the Azure Data Studio's connection but got the following error:

Failed to authenticate the user in Active Directory (Authentication=ActiveDirectoryInteractive).
Error code 0xinvalid_request
AADSTS900021: Requested tenant identifier '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000' is not valid. Tenant identifiers may not be an empty GUID.

The solution for this error seems to be using an older Azure Portal and is not valid Old Solution:
Background:
I created these databases about 10 years ago when Azure was new and I occasionally I get issues through the years where emphasized textthings have been updated and the Microsoft process for moving older stuff to newer stuff had issues.  I don't know if this is like that or not.

Please clarify if you're referring to the dbo schema - or the db_owner role - or the specific user-account listed as the "Owner" in SSMS Database Properties?

To access the DBO (database owner) account in an Azure SQL Database, other than SQL server admin login and password you can use The Microsoft Entra Admin Authentication

Open your Azure SQL Server and add Microsoft Entra User or group (To get access to multiple people) as an admin.
This admin account has administrative privileges over all the databases on the server, including the ability to access the DBO schema.


And login to Azure SQL database through Azure Data Studio by using authentication method as Microsoft Entra Id - Universal with MFA support

